# Excel 365 - change cell background to another cells background in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have column A which turn cells green, yellow or red depending on what you chose from the cells dropdown list (Ok, In progress, Late).

In column B to M I have a time schedule where I have a simple conditional formatting formula that turns the cells green when I enter a value in them. This is to visualize over what time periods the current activity is planned.

```
=B1:M1000 <> ""
```

What I would like instead is to turn cells in B to M to the color of cell A on the corresponding row. So if an activity (a row) is marked as "Ok" I want the time schedule to be green on that row, but if I change activity to "Late" I want the time schedule to turn red.

I have not found any solution to do this with conditional formatting, any ideas? Preferably I would like to avoid VBA since I then have to save the file in different format and I get a warning each time I open it.

Answer (score 0):

Select the area A1:M1000 and put as conditional formula: `=AND($A1="ok",NOT(ISBLANK(A1)))` This will let the columns from A to M same color as A.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I only want this when there actually is anything in the cell. And I am pretty sure this will write an "Ok" in the cell as well and not just the color?

Comment: this goes in the formula inside the conditional formatting rule, i can add a picture for clarity. I will also change the formula to include applying to non-empty cells